# connect.bodyParser is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, body-parser

I am completely new to node.js. I am trying to use bodyParser in connect module, but the error message says `TypeError: connect.bodyParser is not a function`. My code (simplified version) is below; What can I use instead of `connect.bodyParser`?

```
  var connect = require('connect');
  var util = require('util');
  var form = require('fs').readFileSync('form.html');

  var app = connect()
    .use(connect.bodyParser())
    .use(connect.limit('64kb'))
    .use(function(req, res){
      if(req.method === 'POST'){
        res.end(util.inspect(req.body));
      }
      if(req === 'GET'){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
        res.end(form);
      }
    }).listen(3000);
```

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is listed as [supported middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware). It looks like in previous versions `bodyParser` was part of `connect` but now is a separate package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it Like this:-

```
var express = require('express');
//console.log(express.address());
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems I need to study about express a bit more to understand this problem...

Comment: the original question asks about connect

Answer (score 2):

You must be using the lastest *connect* module. In the connect 3+ versions, you don't have bodyParser method anymore. It has been moved to a completely different package of its own called **body-parser**. Read [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

Answer (score 1):

Just like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35152360/4451521) it seems that connect has been deprecated so that bodyParser does not work like that anymore. So you have to install it separatedly with `npm install body-parser` and then use it like `var bodyParser = require('body-parser')`